# Making a web app which allows the user to view the server desktop

Tags: java, python, web-applications

I did a pretty fair bit of scouring, yet could not find anything useful which answers my questions. Either that or I am asking the wrong questions.

I am trying to make a web application which gives a user a graphical view of the server desktop. I have understood that somewhere in here X engine has to be invoked and I have also understood that this is not something that php can accomplish primarily because its a language which processes before sending requests, please correct me if I am wrong in this regard.

You may say that what I am trying to accomplish is something akin to what teamviewer does only on the web. My dilemma is whether I should be using python or java for this task, both would be pretty apt for the task, but which one would be better?

Please give your suggestions

Comment: Have you checked out join.me. It is a web based Remote Client App.

Comment: Take a look on [OpenMeetings](http://openmeetings.apache.org)

Comment: I did not know about these apps previously, but I will check them out. I would rather build it myself because there is a bit of security that I need to maintain, I do not know if the same can be maintained with the same. and above all it would be a really nice personal project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow the user to interact with the desktop in real-time, you need to run the application in the users web browser. Interaction with a webserver would just be too slow to do anything meaningful. I do not know about any way to execute Python in a web browser, so I would rule it out. Some of your options for client-sided code execution are:

- Javascript (the recent addition of Canvas and WebSocket made it suitable for this kind of problem)
- Java Applets (felt out of favor recently due to security problems)
- ActiveX (IE- and Windows only, very rarely used in a public context nowadays)
- Flash (a popular but dying technology)

Comment: @Awalias Skulpt is a Python interpreter written in Javascript. I would rather consider it a novelty or teaching tool than a serious technology for production use.